# Given dimensions are different on 3D printer

Tags: 3d, openscad

I draw a small cap in openSCAD and defined the dimensions in 'mm'.

When I export the part as STL and open it in the 3D printer's software, the part is almost double in size.

here is the part's code:

```
difference() {
    cylinder(h = 15, r1 = 35, r2 = 35);
    cylinder(h = 12, r1 = 32, r2 = 32);
    cylinder(h = 50, r1 = 3, r2 = 3);
}
```

The render shows the inner edge around 32mm, and outer around 35mm. But 
3D printer shows 70mm radious. I am started to use openSCAD a week ago and I did not have any ratio issues with previous test prints (cube, pyramid, etc). This is the 1st real life I designed and I have a ratio issue. I can scale down the model in 3D printer software but I would like to know the reason behind it, so I can design future stuff accordingly.

Edit: I scaled down 50% and printed. The outside radius was correct, but all other dimensions (the height, wall the thickness) were also 50% scaled down. So only the outside radius was incorrect at the beginning.

[image: Render in openSCAD]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's exactly 50% too wide?

Remember that r stands for *radius*, and that radius is *half* of your diameter.

It sounds to me like you filled in the diameter values when you meant to fill in the radius values.

Comment: You were right, it was an old habit from SolidWorks.